# Mysql Very Long Time in Query Execution

Tags: mysql, sql

I have get the query in this thread [Sum Multiple Row Date Difference Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292543/sum-multiple-row-date-difference-mysql/16294410?noredirect=1#16294410)

The problem now is that the query execution time is so long. I try with a little row data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d496/1/0.
And it is like crazy thing when i try to execute this query in my local database (my table total row is about 200.000 row), because there is no result even when I wait in a very long time.

I want to ask, is this query by default need a long time to execute? Is it possible to make it faster? How? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried this on a shorter table to see if a result is populated?

Comment: @brendan morrison He has, please check the second link in his question

Comment: I suspect that the reason why this is slow is because of the subquery, that could potentially be run once for every single row selected. Does mysql have partition, perhaps? Are you indexing your table on date? Or perhaps if you generate for the table an integer which increases by 1 for every successive row by date, then index/write your query against this integer? That way you don't need to do a subquery to find what the previous row is.

Comment: join without indexing is horrible

Comment: Check my answer to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding Speed to your index:

KEY `LogCarIdx` (`LogDate`,`CarId`, `Speed`)

Then the c1 based query uses the index (so says explain).  Can't tell the speed difference in the sqlfiddle, but might help in the full size query.